# How can I know what went wrong in the execution of my sql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I execute a mysql statement via php, no exception is thrown, but nothing happens

The statement is actually multiple statement set separated by ; which should have created multiple tables

How can I check what went wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It depend on the API you are using ; but those are generally providing a way of getting an error message, when a query fails.

See, typically :

- [`mysql_error()`](http://fr.php.net/mysql_error)
- [`mysqli_error()`](http://fr.php.net/mysqli_error)
- [`PDO::errorInfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Also, to give some information that's probably more related to your question : you are saying *(quoting)* :

> The statement is actually **multiple
> statement set** separated by ; ...

This is typically not supported by default functions.

For instance, the documentation of [`mysql_query()`][1] states *(quoting)* :

> multiple queries are not supported

If you are using `mysqli_*` functions, take a look at [`mysqli::multi_query()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you running the sql statement in phpmyadmin to see what happens.

Comment: +1, though I would add that the command line or any other software that parses MySQL will serve just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call mysql_query() for each query.
You can't put them all within a single call, even though they are separated by ";"